# Batch File "echo" and function output not correct

Tags: batch-file

I am having trouble with my "echo" output.

I have 3 functions (Speak, SpeakByChoice, SpeakChoose) and 1 label (Play)

Here is my code so far...

```
@ echo off
title Text Story Game

:Main
color 9f
echo ====== Main Menu ======
echo 1) Play
echo 2) Password
echo 3) Quit
set /p mainMenuChoice=
if %mainMenuChoice% == 1 goto Play
if %mainMenuChoice% == 2 goto Password
if %mainMenuChoice% == 3 exit
goto Main

:Play
REM Gameplay Start
call :Speak "Mayor" "Mmm, oh, I didn't see you there!"
call :Speak "Mayor" "Hello there! Welcome to Rockwell Town, er...who are you?"
set /p name= Choose your name: 
call :Speak "Mayor" "Oh, why hello %name%! Good to meet you."
call :Speak "Mayor" "What did you come here for?"
call :SpeakChoose "I need a favor done." "Um, nothing..." (here is problem)
pause
pause

:Speak
echo.
echo [ %~1 ^>^> %~2 ] 
pause>nul
goto :EOF

:SpeakByChoice
echo.
call :Speak %~1 %~2
call :Speak %~3 %~4
goto :EOF

:SpeakChoose
echo.
echo [ Choice: ]
echo 1) %~1
echo 2) %~2
set /p SpeakChoose=
if %SpeakChoose% == 1 call :SpeakByChoice "%name%" "%~1" "Mayor" "Okay, what can I help you with?" 
if %SpeakChoose% == 2 call :SpeakByChoice "%name%" "%~2" "Mayor" "Oh okay....wait a minute. Didn't you ask me about moving in earlier?"
goto :EOF

:DNCSpeakChoose
echo.
echo You didn't choose anything.....
call :Speak "%name%" "..."
```

Although the output is this:

My name is "(blank)" but it shows as "I" in the SpeakByChoice call but not in the other calls like Speak

```
====== Main Menu ======
1) Play
2) Password
3) Quit
1

[ Mayor >> Mmm, oh, I didn't see you there! ] ↓

[ Mayor >> Hello there! Welcome to Rockwell Town, er...who are you? ] ↓
Choose your name: (not chosen...)

[ Mayor >> Oh, why hello (blank name IS here) ! Good to meet you. ] ↓

[ Mayor >> What did you come here for? ] ↓

[ Choice: ]
1) I need a favor done.
2) Um, nothing...
1


[ I (who is I?? this should've been blank) >> need ] ↓

[ Mayor >> Okay ] ↓
Press any key to continue . . .
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I am unsure what is triggering this problem. Is it something with SETLOCAL, or my :EOF, I don't know. But my Speak and SpeakChoose function works perfect, but my SpeakByChoice  does not.

Comment: Put double quotes around the parameters in the calls, if you un-quote them. `call :Speak "%~1" "%~2"` in speakbychoice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add some quotes.  This worked great for me.

```
@echo off
title Text Story Game

:Main
color 9f
echo ====== Main Menu ======
echo 1) Play
echo 2) Password
echo 3) Quit
set /p mainMenuChoice=
if %mainMenuChoice% == 1 goto Play
if %mainMenuChoice% == 2 goto Password
if %mainMenuChoice% == 3 exit
goto Main

:Play
REM Gameplay Start
call :Speak "Mayor" "Mmm, oh, I didn't see you there!"
call :Speak "Mayor" "Hello there! Welcome to Rockwell Town, er...who are you?"
set /p name= Choose your name: 
call :Speak "Mayor" "Oh, why hello %name%! Good to meet you."
call :Speak "Mayor" "What did you come here for?"
call :SpeakChoose "I need a favor done." "Um, nothing..." (here is problem)
pause
pause

:Speak
echo.
echo [ %~1 ^>^> %~2 ] 
pause>nul
goto :EOF

:SpeakByChoice
echo.
call :Speak "%~1" "%~2"
call :Speak "%~3" "%~4"
goto :EOF

:SpeakChoose
echo.
echo [ Choice: ]
echo 1) %~1
echo 2) %~2
set /p SpeakChoose=
if %SpeakChoose% == 1 call :SpeakByChoice "%name%" "%~1" "Mayor" "Okay, what can I help you with?" 
if %SpeakChoose% == 2 call :SpeakByChoice "%name%" "%~2" "Mayor" "Oh okay....wait a minute. Didn't you ask me about moving in earlier?"
goto :EOF

:DNCSpeakChoose
echo.
echo You didn't choose anything.....
call :Speak "%name%" "..."
```